# Extract values from cell and copy entire row with each individual value

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column which consists of 3 digit codes referring to a branch. If a person is working in multiple departments, then he/she will have multiple codes referred in that column. Below is what it would look like.

```
Name  | Branch
ABC   | 423
MNO   |  367325
XYZ   |  414426429
```

I want it to look like this.

```
Name |  Branch
ABC  |  423
MNO  |  367
MNO  |  325
XYZ  |  414
XYZ  |  426
XYZ  |  429
```

I want to extract the value of the cell, suppose let's say the string length is 9, then that person works for 3 branches. I want to extract those 3 values and duplicate the entire row with each row containing one branch number.

A few pointers : No person can work for more than **3 branches**(so maximum string length will be **9**). There are about **20 columns**. The column which contains the branch codes is always the same i.e. **column G**. The column also has **empty cells** and other string values like '**BIKCJHGT**'. **The entire column is formatted as text.**

Can any one please give me the VBA code to accomplish this?

Here is the code I've used. It hasn't thrown any errors, but it's not working either.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MultiRecords()

    Dim b As Workbook

    Set b = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\uspola00\Desktop\Headcount_Final.xlsx")
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Headcount").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range("G1").Select

    Dim ws As Worksheet    
    Set ws = Sheets("Headcount")
    Dim intInsertRows As Integer  
    Dim i As Long

    i = 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Do Until i > ws.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim str As String
        str = LTrim(RTrim(ws.Range("G" & i)))  
        If Len("G" & i) = 9 Then
            intInsertRows = 2
            Range("G" & i + 1 & ":G" & i + intInsertRows).EntireRow.Insert 
            Range("A" & i & ":N" & (i + intInsertRows)).FillDown
            Range("G" & (i + intInsertRows)).Value = Right(str, 3)
            Range("G" & i + 1).Value = Mid(str, 4, 3)
            Range("G" & i).Value = Left(str, 3)
            i = i + intInsertRows
        ElseIf Len("G" & i) = 6 Then
            intInsertRows = 1
            Range("G" & i & ":G" & i + intInsertRows).EntireRow.Insert
            Range("A" & i & ":N" & (i + intInsertRows)).FillDown
            Range("G" & i + intInsertRows).Value = Right(str, 3)
            Range("G" & i).Value = Left(str, 3)
            i = i + intInsertRows
        ElseIf Len("G" & i) = 3 Then
            intInsertRows = 0
            i = i + intInsertRows    
        ElseIf IsEmpty(Range("G" & i)) Then
            i = i + 0
        End If
        i = i + 1 
    Loop   

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub MultiRecords()

    Dim b As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range, v, i As Long

    Set b = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\uspola00\Desktop\Headcount_Final.xlsx")
    Set ws = b.Sheets("Headcount")
    Set c = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp)

    Do
       v = Trim(c.Value)
       If v Like "######" Or v Like "#########" Then
           i = Len(v) / 3
           c.Offset(1, 0).Resize(i - 1).EntireRow.Insert
           c.Resize(i).EntireRow.FillDown
           c.Value = Left(v, 3)
           c.Offset(1, 0).Value = Mid(v, 4, 3)
           If Len(v) = 9 Then c.Offset(2, 0).Value = Right(v, 3)
       End If

       If c.Row = 1 Then Exit Do
       Set c = c.Offset(-1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```